# Is there any way in CakePHP3 to have an entity that inherits from a parent class but that parent doesn't have a corresponding table?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I want to be able to write to class2's table by calling class1.  Possible?

```
public class1 extends Entity{
 public function save(){
 }
}

public class2 extends class1{
}

class class1Controller extends AppController{
public function test(){
    class1->save();
}
}
```

Comment: I don't know CakePHP, but generally what you are trying to do should be possible. Hint: You probably need to create an instance of the class you want to access (e.g. `$obj = new Class2();`) and make that call to the object. (`$obj->save();`). To read more about Classes are Types, see: http://php.net/manual/language.oop5.basic.php

Comment: Entities should not contain saving logic, that's what table classes are there for. You may want to reword your question. Also supplying information about the actual problem that you're facing with your approach is always helpful.

Comment: What is the line `class1->save();` even supposed to do? That's not valid syntax, so your intent is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 formally associated models, calling saveAll on one will update the data in the other as well.  But note that what you show us declares no association..